# An abelian group $A$ equal to $\ker\phi\oplus A'$ where $A'=\Bbb{Z}a_1\oplus\cdots\oplus\Bbb{Z}a_r$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $A$ be abelian group and $L$ a free abelian group of finite rank, and $\phi:A\to L$ a morphism.
>
> Choosing a base $(l_1,\ldots,l_r)$ of $L$ and $(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ such that $\forall i: \phi(a_i)=l_i.$
>
> Show that $\ker\phi\oplus A'=A$ where $A'=\Bbb{Z}a_1\oplus\cdots\oplus\Bbb{Z}a_r$, not sure how can I prove that, I can prove that the set $(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ is linearly independent.

If I 'play' with $x\in A$ such that $x=y+a'$ where $y\in \ker\phi$ and $a'\in A'$, I get $\phi(x)=\phi(a')$

As $x\in A$ we have $\phi(x)\in L$ wich means that $\phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_il_i$ and $a'\in A'$ means that $a$ can be written as $a'=\beta_1a_1+\cdots+\beta_ra_r$ and then $\phi(a')=\beta_1l_1+\beta_2l_2+\cdots+\beta_rl_r$, not sure that helps either.

In fact, I am pretty sure that I am not understanding correctly the 'role' of $(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ being linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\{a_1,\ldots,a_r\}$ must be linearly independent; otherwise $\phi(a_i) = l_i$ would be impossible. (Any linear relation between the $a_i$ would give one on the $l_i$ via $\phi$.)

Now given an element $a \in A$, you get $\phi(a) = \sum_i c_i l_i$ for a unique tuple of integers $(c_i)$. Then $a - \sum_i c_i a_i$ is in $\ker \phi$. Can you show that $a = \left( a - \sum_i c_i a_i \right) + \left(\sum_i c_i a_i\right) \in \ker \phi + A'$ gives you a direct sum decomposition of $A$?

Comment: It was trivial but I didn't see it :( ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $\psi=\phi|_{A'}: A' \to L$ is a bijection, it is pretty straightforward that any element not in the kernel has at least one non-zero coefficient in the $a_i$s expression. That is, if $x \not\in \ker(\phi)$ then $0 \neq \phi(x) = b_1 l_1 + \dots + b_n l_n$, where not all $b_i$ are zero. But then applying $\psi^{-1}$ you get what I said.
This means that every element can be decomposed as
$$x = \sum b_i a_i + (x-\sum b_i a_i)$$
which is what gives you the decomposition. It remains to prove that it's direct but, since the trivial intersection part is trivial, you get that $A=\ker(\phi) \oplus A'$